# Please explain me the behavior of Bootstrap grids for this specific example

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I am learning bootstrap ver 4.4.1 and trying to understand this code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">1</div>               <!--First line-->
<div class="col-sm">2</div>            <!--Second line-->        
<div class="col">3</div>               <!--Third line--> 
</div>
</div>
```

For breakpoint <576px I am getting 3 vertically stacked rows spanning the entire container.
However according to bootstrap auto column layout the col in first line ad col in third line should form col-6 for first line and third line respectively and should show 50% width for col in first row and 50% width for col third row along with entire span of column in row 2

And why it shows 3 columns in horizontal position when we are in breakpoint of small devices which is >= 576px can some one explain me this deviation in output from what I expected. I am attaching the images for original output and my expected output .image is here [image: Sample image]

Comment: Your question needs to be more focused, try not ask many things at once

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: because that's how it is supposed to work.

> However according to bootstrap auto column layout the col in first line ad col in third line should form col-6 for first line and third line respectively and should show 50% width for col in first row and 50% width for col third row along with entire span of column in row 2

I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but this is not how `col` vs `col-sm` is working. They aren't indicators of how much width they occupy, but simply *when* they should be taken into account.

`col` and `col-sm` both try to adjust their size according to the other elements in the [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). But `col-sm` only does so for breakpoint `sm` and higher. This is why you are getting the three horizontal columns on `sm` and higher (all three columns are part of the flexbox and assume an equal width and layout).

Once you get to `xs` the `col-sm` class "loses" its flexbox attributes and no longer is sized in relation to the flex elements (column 1 and column 3), but instead assumes a width of 100%. That in turn causes the other two columns to also auto-size to 100% because they no longer can auto-layout to 33%.

To get the result you want, you have to actually specify the width of your columns with `col-*`.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-12">2</div>
    <div class="col-6">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```